# samsung MD230X3 width when bended

Tags: multiple-monitors

does anyone know the width of this nice setup when the 2 side monitors are bended towards you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Samsung specifications page for that model](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/monitors/LS23MUQHB/ZA-features):

> Landscape: 62.43" x 22.11" x 12.09" With Stand
>   Portrait: 36.38" x 26.48" x 12.09" With Stand

So that would be 1.59 meters in landscape or 0.924 meters in portrait.

That's the maximum width with the screens spread out straight.

According to [this spec sheet](http://www.samsung.com/us/system/consumer/product/ls/23/mu/ls23muqhbza/MD230_MD230X3_MD230X6_DSHT.pdf) (PDF), the screens can be bent 30° so with a little trig, the **minimum width** for landscape mode would be **56.9 inches** (1.45 meters) or **33.1 inches** (0.841 meters) in portrait mode.

[image: Samsung MD230X3 23" (x3) Multi-Display Monitor]